# AvaloniaUI: DirectProperty in UserControl

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm trying to learn AvaloniaUI.
I would like to know how DirectProperties work.

So:
I created a UserControl: TestUC
I added a DirectProperty in it: Value
I added 4 TextBoxes. 2 of them in the MainView and 2 in the TestUC.
I added bindings to the "greeting" field in the MainViewModel.

I try to sync all 4 TextBoxes. Just to learn how DirectoProperty works.
The 2 TextBoxes in the TestUC are not synced with the others. So It looks like I miss something with DirectProperties.

[I have a github repo here to show this.](https://github.com/metheofanis/TestAvalonia/tree/master/TestAvalonia)

What do I miss?

Here is the relevant part in `MainView.axaml`

```
<StackPanel>
            <Label Content="First in MainView"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Greeting}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

            <Label Content="Second in MainView"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Greeting}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

            <Label Content="UserControl"/>          
            <uc:TestUC Value="{Binding Greeting}"/>     
</StackPanel>
```

TestUC.axaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

TestUC.axaml.cs

```
public static readonly DirectProperty<TestUC, string> ValueProperty =
   AvaloniaProperty.RegisterDirect<TestUC, string>(
       nameof(Value),
       o => o.Value,
       (o, v) => o.Value = v,
       defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

private string _value;

public string Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set { SetAndRaise(ValueProperty, ref _value, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User Controls is not design for this scenarios ...look at [Types of Custom Controls](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/guides/custom-controls/types-of-control) Templated control is what I will choose

`StyledProperty` is more suited than `DirectProperty`, because your property will use the Avalonia Style system

the following is what you want create a Templated control called `MyContorl` in Controls namespace

```cs
public class MyControl : TemplatedControl
{
    public static readonly StyledProperty<string> ValueProperty =
       AvaloniaProperty.Register<MyControl, string>(
           nameof(Value),
           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string Value
    {
        get => GetValue(ValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }
}
```

and create a template for it

```xml
<Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="using:TestAvalonia.Controls">
  <Design.PreviewWith>
    <controls:MyControl />
  </Design.PreviewWith>

  <Style Selector="controls|MyControl">
    <!-- Set Defaults -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <ControlTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <Label Content="one way binding"/>
          <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Value}"/>
          <Label Content="Two way binndign"/>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Styles>
```

and include this style in your Application style

```xml
<StyleInclude Source="/Controls/MyControl.axaml"/>
```

finally use it as you expect

```xml
xmlns:controls ="using:TestAvalonia.Controls"
....
<Label Content="controls"/>
<controls:MyControl Value="{Binding Greeting}"/>
```

I have create [Pull request in your GitHub](https://github.com/metheofanis/TestAvalonia/pull/1) with this changes

Comment: I've tested it and it's working. I really appreciate your help. Thanks!